# Rebus: Is it possible to get message headers in Autofac instance pr dependecy

Tags: rebus

Is there a way to setup Rebus and Autocac so that properties in the message headers could be used to setup services in Autofac, in an instance pr dependencies scenario?

The use case is a service that have an application id in the message headers and that setup the correct credentials on a pr message basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's definitely possible - the current message context has the headers and it is ready and available at the time when handlers are resolved.

It is just a matter of registering a factory method with Autofac, and then you can access the message context via the static `MessageContext.Current` property.

I don't know what it looks like with Autofac, but with Windsor I would do something like this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ISomeService>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => {
            var context = MessageContext.Current;
            if (context == null) { 
                var msg = "Must be inside Rebus handler to do this";
                throw new InvalidOperationException(msg); 
            }

            var headers = context.Headers;

            // decide which implementation of ISomeService
            // to return here.....
            return new ConcreteService();
        }, managedExternally: true)
        .LifestyleTransient()
);
```

I hope you can translate the Windsor snippet to something equivalent in Autofac.

Comment: The MessageContext.Current is available in the context of the DI ?

Comment: Yes it is :) it's just a static gateway to a `MessageContext` instance, which is bound to the thread using `LogicalCallContext` so it flows properly to continuations

Comment: Thanks for the input